# Struggling to grab data from baseball reference

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the tables for all pitchers batting against found on [this page.](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2022-batting-pitching.shtml)

I believe the problems lies with the data being behind a comment.

For the sake of the example, I'd like to find, say, Sandy Alcantara's home runs allowed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url="https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2022-batting-pitching.shtml"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(page.content,"html.parser")
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    td=tr.find_all('td')
    print(td)
```

This prints a lot of team data, but doesn't print the pitcher data.

How can I cleverly get it to print the pitcher data? Ideally, I'd have it in a list or something.

```
object[0]=Rk 
object[1]=Name
object[4]=IP 
object[13]=HR
```

Comment: You can export the table you need as csv.

Comment: For sure. In this case, I'd like to use this data in a program that runs daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem related to the extraction of the table content is that the table itself is stored inside a comment string.

After you have fetched your web page, and loaded it into BeautifulSoup, you can solve this web page scraping issue following these steps:

- gather the div tagged `id = 'all_players_batting_pitching'`, which contains your table
- extract the table from the comments using the `decode_contents` function, then reloading your text into a soup
- extract each record of your table by looking for the `tr` tag, then each value by looking for the `td` tag, if that value is included in your indices [1, 4, 13]
- load your values into a Pandas.DataFrame, ready to be used

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

# fetching web page
url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2022-batting-pitching.shtml"
page = requests.get(url)

# extracting table from html
soup = bs(page.content,"html.parser")
table = soup.find(id = 'all_players_batting_pitching')
tab_text = table.decode_contents().split('--')[1].strip()

tab_soup = bs(tab_text,"html.parser")

# extracting records from table
records = []
for i, row in enumerate(tab_soup.find_all('tr')):
    record = [ele.text.strip() for j, ele in enumerate(row.find_all('td')) if j in [0, 3, 12]]
    if record != []:
        records.append([row.a['href']] + [i] + record)
```

Output:

```
    href    Rk  Name    IP  HR
0   /players/a/abbotco01.shtml  1   Cory Abbott     48.0    12
1   /players/a/abreual01.shtml  2   Albert Abreu    38.2    5
2   /players/a/abreual01.shtml  3   Albert Abreu    8.2     2
3   /players/a/abreual01.shtml  4   Albert Abreu    4.1     1
4   /players/a/abreual01.shtml  5   Albert Abreu    25.2    2
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1063    /players/z/zastrro01.shtml  1106    Rob Zastryzny*  1.0     0
1064    /players/z/zastrro01.shtml  1107    Rob Zastryzny*  3.0     0
1065    /players/z/zerpaan01.shtml  1108    Angel Zerpa*    11.0    2
1066    /players/z/zeuchtj01.shtml  1109    T.J. Zeuch  10.2    5
1067    /players/z/zimmebr02.shtml  1110    Bruce Zimmermann*   73.2    21
```

Comment: Error better described below

Comment: Copy-paste this code in a clean environment, it should work for you. What error are you getting?

Comment: So sorry. The enter is very sensitive. I did and it boils down to:   File "/home/ken/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 302, in encodings
    self.markup, self.is_html)
  File "/home/ken/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 378, in find_declared_encoding
    declared_encoding_match = xml_re.search(markup, endpos=xml_endpos)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Although the reference of your error doesn't touch my snippet. You're having a further error which is out of topic with respect to "*Struggling to grab data from baseball reference*".

Comment: I would agree. I'll do my best to sort it out from here. Thank you so much for getting me the next step!

Comment: One more question: A few players played for multiple teams (Albert Abreu) and a couple players have non-unique names (Luis Castillo). The players have an ID (Albert Abreu's is abreual01). This is noted in two places. 1 data-append-csv="abreual01" and 2. <a href="/players/a/abreual01".shtml". Is there a way I can pull this unique ID to ignore players who are already in the dataframe and separate players with non-unique names?

Comment: It's necessary to extract the attribute `href` from each row of the table. I've added it's extraction to the snippet with ``[row.a['href']]``. Check the output.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thank you so much. I learned a ton.